# How to avoid Called 'load' without the :safe option — defaulting to safe mode warning?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, yaml

When i start thin server i get the following

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000  
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Called 'load' without the :safe option -- defaulting to safe mode.
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to  1024 
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3001, CTRL+C to stop
```

and i confirmed that the above warning is coming from safe_yaml gem, and i configure my yml file like this

```
YAML.load_file("test.yml", :safe => true)
```

but still i get the above warning message, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Write a ruby program that opens every file in your project and searches through the files for lines with 'YAML.load'. Have the program print the line and the filename. Then open up each of the files in which 'YAML.load' was found, and if any of the calls to YAML.load do not use the safe option, change the code.